# How to save an image to Gtk Clipboard without creating a window?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am trying to take a pixbuf image and drop it into the user's clipboard for pasting into any program that accepts images. If I don't run `Gtk.main()`, nothing happens. If I do run `Gtk.main()`, it works, but the program never exits (I don't want to open a window).

```py
# pixbuf is a pixbuf image

clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
clipboard.set_image(pixbuf)
clipboard.store()

Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have bad news, and I suggest you use something other than gtk to set the clipboard. I recommend trying something like [wl-clipboard](https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard), xsel, or xclip. I am sure you know how to chose one or two of these and call it from a python script.

If you are looking for a gtk-only solution, I have spent quite some time on this and given up though I am not yet an expert in any of this.

The traditional solution is documented here:
https://github.com/bstpierre/gtk-examples/blob/master/c/clipboard_simple.c.
For reasons beyond my knowledge it doesn't currently work, but the comments at the bottom would be important in creating a gtk-only solution. The problem could be for a number of reasons including a bug in gtk or glibc. Or it might be part of a poorly explained migration to wayland.

Another potential solution is documented here: https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/func.events_pending.html. This also doesn't work for unknown reasons.

The next avenues for testing are to test historical versions of linux distributions, and once the library version is found try to pinpoint the exact commit to the exact library and make a change. I made a decent effort to debug gtk, but it is not yet my area of expertise.

Even if the the change could be maid to facilitate one of the above solutions, it would be to much to ask for a version that works on wayland. Although xwayland may offer residual support and wl-clipboard offers a hack, any clipboard read or write requires a window and for your window to be focused as mentioned here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/1874. There seams to be some exeption for non-gnome wayland implied in this discussion: https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard/issues/90. Although I never found the offending part of the wayland standard, I expect that it is present.